# How to get my product IEC tested and certified

Tags: electrical-engineering, product-testing, regulations

What is the procedure to get proper IEC certification for a product? What is cost of such action? I am talking about, let's say, a fan or an oven (if size and complexity of product makes any difference)

Comment: I would start talking to a testing house? These are two that I am aware of [SGS Testing](https://www.sgsgroup.us.com/en/testing and [Intertek](https://www.intertek.com/). Based on the product you will have to develop a test plan.

Comment: CSA is another testing house. Depending on the complexity and number of tests needed, typical agency listing is $25-75,000